# Facebook Premium Content

Tags: php, facebook, payment

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/creditsapi/ info and sample codes about payments are available from this souce link. I need to learn how to show or hide content in my app. Like if a user is paid and has premium account, that user should see the exclusive content but the free user should not see the exclusive content.
I mean;

> Paid users will see "A" content...
>
> Free users will see "B" content...

I want to divide the things my users can see, if they're premium or not.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What's your question? What have you tried?

Comment: I want to separate the content that premium users can use and free users cant.

Comment: Surely you can write to your own database of who has paid and who has not?

Comment: @Metin I am sorry, but "I want to separate the content that premium users can use and free users cant." is not a question. What have you tried?

Comment: @Scuzzy came to my mind but i want to learn it can be done using the facebook graph api.

Comment: @Johannes I know so much English. You understand my problem! You ask in my name ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have muich experience with the Facebook API, but I believe this snippet from your link is what you are looking for:

> When this has been completed, Facebook will once again callback to
>   your callback URL with the method "payments_status_update" and the
>   "status" variable set to "settled". This is when you will definitively
>   know that the transaction was completed successfully and you can then
>   perform any  operations to give the item to the user.

All you need to do is to record a flag in your database field. NOTE: I am assuming you have lots of products stored in a `products` table, and lots of users stored in a `users` table. In the users table, you would probably have to store their facebook id (not the username, the numerical ID), to identify them in the future.

1. When facebook does a call back to `payments_status_update` with the `status` set to `settled`, you need to create a link between the `products` and `users` table using an intersection table called `products_users`. (This means that the user now owns this product/content).
2. When the user hits your app, you grab their numerical userid, and then check if a link exists between their ID and the `products` table via `products_users`. If there is, you can write an SQL query to retrieve a list of products they have brought. Based on this, you shoudl be able to determine if the user can see the premium content or not.

Comment: I do not understand how to use or gave the examples given in error.